# How to navigate to different page after phone unlocked in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, locking

I have automatic logout scenario in my app. where, i need to logout and navigate to login page after 20mins. it works fine when app is in foreground. but, if it is locked and unlocked, it is not working.

Can anyone tell me how to stop resetting the previous page and navigate to different page in wp8 app??

Answer (score 1):

When users lock phone or switch to another app your app executes `Application_Deactivated` and when it comes back to foreground it executes `Application_Activated` (In your `App` class).

You can save last activation time in `Application_Deactivated` and check if it is 20mins later in `Application_Activated`.

**EDIT:** For navigating in `Application_Activated`, you can use this code:

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    RootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated;
}

void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    RootFrame.Navigated -= RootFrame_Navigated;
    RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Yes. you are correct. currently, i am doing that as you have described. But, the problem is, after 20mins, i cannot navigate to LoginPage from Application_Activated. application is trying to reset the navigation after phone is unlocked and navigating to the previous page, intaed of LoginPage.

Comment: i am getting InvalidOperationException when i am trying to navigate from Application_Activated.

Comment: @user3730360 Sorry I just found it, after some tests you can use the code in edited main answer.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I tried as you have suggested. It is navigating to different page. But, after un-lock the device, it first navigates to previous page and then navigates to TestPage.xaml. 
But, as i know that session is timedout, i dont want to navigate to previous page. i want to directly navigate to TestPage.xaml.

Is it possible to cancel/override the navigation happening from Application_Activated event?

Comment: i get below Exception. if i try to navigate from Application_activated event:
{System.InvalidOperationException: Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground.
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(Uri source)

Comment: @user3730360 Maybe you can navigate to a _middle_ page when deactivation (listen for `RootFrame.Navigating`, when navigating to outside of app, navigate to middle page, it works), and determine what's the next page to navigate (go back to true last page or go to login page) when navigated back. But I think the above code is enough, it will navigate to `TestPage.xaml` as soon as the old page loaded.

Comment: The solution of handling in RootFrame.Navigating doesnot work as expected. it always navigates to LoginPage, even if i remove single back entry to make it navigate to last page if the session is valid:(
Is there any other possible solution of cancel/override the navigation happening from Application_Activated event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `App.RootFrame`'s `Unobscured` event for this. Attach the event handler like this in your MainPage.xaml

```
App.RootFrame.Unobscured += RootFrame_Unobscured;
```

And in the event handler navigate to the page.

```
 void RootFrame_Unobscured(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

Comment: I have already tried with RootFrame_Unobscured event. Even RootFrame_Unobscured works after previous page gets loaded. But, i don't want to load the previous page if session is timeout.